# Cookie Clicker Cheats

Tags: cheats, cookie-clicker

Is there a way to cheat on cookie clicker, without inspecting the game? Because I'm on a school computer, and I can't use the inspect feature so. I just want a faster way to make cookies, if someone could help me with this. That will be very helpful, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are on an older version that has legacy or these won't work.
Type in next to your name `saysopenesame` but make sure it fits.
One more tip by the way is that cookie farms have gardens. When you level them up, name yourself `orteil` and you will get -1cps and if you spell it `ortiel` you will get -2cps.

Answer (score 1):

Use bookmarklets.  For example, type in your address bar `javascript:Game.saysopenesame()` and it will work.  For anything else, just paste the javascript in that address bar and type `javascript:` in front of it.

This will work on other sites too, i.e `javascript:alet('You ave been hacked.');` will make an alert.

Answer (score 0):

If you add saysopensesame to the end of your bakery's then you can get a cheat console of sorts but if you want to play "beat" the game without using any cheats/ hack methods then I suggest just leaving the game window open on the side of your computer at all times even if you're doing something else so it won't count you as Idle.